# How to set all possible relationships of has_many as default in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

In our SilverStripe project `NavBlock` `has_many` `SiteModes`:

```
class NavBlock extends DataObject
{
    private static $has_many = array(
        'SiteModes' => 'SiteMode'
    );
}
```

How do I set the default for `NavBlock` to have a `has_many` relationship with all available `SiteModes`?

I would like to have this relationship appear when a new `NavBlock` is created and applied to all existing `NavBlocks`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps something like an `onBeforeWrite()` which checks if there are any SiteModes, and if not then applies all available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add each `SiteMode` in the class `onAfterWrite` function:

```
class NavBlock extends DataObject {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'SiteModes' => 'SiteMode'
    );

    protected function onAfterWrite() {
        parent::onAfterWrite();

        if ($this->SiteModes()->count() === 0) {
            $siteModes = SiteMode::get();

            foreach ($siteModes as $siteMode) {
                $this->SiteModes()->add($siteMode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```